# unable the change the font of card view

Tags: android

i am changing the font of my app globally by using Typeface but the font of all other activities changed  but the text inside card view does not changed. My code is:

public class ReplaceFont {

```
public  static  void ReplaceDefaultFont(Context context, String OldFont, String Newfont){

   final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/07722-cgothic.ttf");
    replaceFont(OldFont,typeface);
}

private static void replaceFont(String oldFont, Typeface typeface) {
    try{

        final Field field = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(oldFont);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(null,typeface);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}
and in main activity:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/07722-
 cgothic.ttf");
```

Comment: Why not create a custom TextView that uses your custom font then simply use the custom textview in your views?

Comment: but i want to chnage the font of whole app not only textviews

Comment: thks for efforts i solved my issue

Comment: Great that you solved it! How did you do it? I am having the same issue. My custom font works for all the app but don't for CardViews... soooo weird...

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

you can use this https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy
It change in your application

compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'

it my be help you.